# How can i get my ip adress in an vpn-connected Fritzbox?

Tags: python-3.x, networking, vpn, ipv4

My office-Fritzbox connected via VPN and DynDNS with my home-Fritzbox vice versa

netmask office 10.131.131.0
netmask home 10.131.10.0

If if use terminal: traceroute to office from home i get:

traceroute to 10.131.131.13 (10.131.131.13), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
1  10.131.10.254 (10.131.10.254)  20.553 ms  0.973 ms  0.919 ms
2  10.131.131.13 (10.131.131.13)  10.949 ms  10.393 ms  10.916 ms
3  10.131.131.13 (10.131.131.13)  11.520 ms  10.980 ms  11.746 ms

but i want to know the ip-adress within the office-net e.g. 10.131.131.?

how can i get it (in Python)
i am using MacOS an Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Support of AVM answers:
If a LAN-LAN connection is set up as described in this guide (set up VPN between two FRITZ!Boxes for individual LAN connections), your end device does not receive an IP address from the remote network. When there is a request to the remote network, the VPN connection is established automatically and the request is sent to the remote FRITZ!Box and forwarded to a device there, for example.